# Error in XML Schema generated from MOXy JAXB when using @XmlPath and namespace

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces, moxy

I am trying to map a java model into some XML. To do this I am using the MOXy implementation of JAXB. I have run into some troubles generating a valid XML Schema from the java model. I use the following model:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class FooBar {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlPath("test/@foo")
    private boolean foo;
}
```

And I am generating the schema with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SchemaOutputResolver sor = new SchemaOutputResolver() {
        @Override
        public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
            return new StreamResult(System.out);
        }
    };

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FooBar.class);
    jc.generateSchema(sor);
}
```

And I use the following package-info.java file:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://moxy.test", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package test.moxy;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

When running the test I obtain the following schema:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:ns0="http://moxy.test" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://moxy.test" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:complexType name="big">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="test" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence/>
               <xsd:attribute ref="ns0:foo"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="big" type="ns0:big"/>
   <xsd:attribute name="foo" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

It can be seen that the last attribute element is not what one would expect. If I remove the package-info.java file, the following schema is generated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="fooBar">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="test" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence/>
               <xsd:attribute name="foo" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="fooBar" type="fooBar"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Which is what I would expect being generated. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This issue (https://bugs.eclipse.org/354130) has now been fixed in our EclipseLink 2.3.1 and 2.4.0 streams, and will be available from our nightly download site starting August 9th, 2011:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer Blaise. I'm a little unsure about the workaround, which results in the following element definition in the schema <xsd:element name="@foo" type="xsd:boolean"/>. First of all I would expect it to be an attribute definition like <xsd:attribute name="foo" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>, and the second thing is that the "@foo" element is not a valid name, according to Eclipses' schema checker.

Comment: @Kasper - You are correct, I did not look closely enough at the output from the workaround.  I will get back to you on this issue soon.